# CrudRepository and Hibernate: save(List<S>) vs save(Entity) in transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Would it make any difference if I do:

```
@Transactional
public void processData() {
    List<MyEntity> entities = ....;
    MyEntityRepository.save(entities);
}
```

vs.

```
@Transactional
public void processData() {
    List<MyEntity> entities = ....;
    for (MyEntity entity : entities) {
        MyEntityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

What is the difference in terms of the underlying queries and performance?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From `SimpleJpaRepository`:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> More save(Iterable<S> entities) {

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    if (entities == null) {
        return result;
    }

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

So, your second business method only shadows `save(Iterable<S> entities)` Crud Repository method, in the sense that it iterates the list and calls `save(S)` on your behalf.

As long as **transaction is demarcated** from your `processData` business method, there is no really a difference in performance or queries executed.

Comment: If my list contains multiple Entities with the same primary key and then I call `save(List<S> entities)`, it gives constraint exception. However, if I iterate (i.e the second business method), it doesn't complain. Why is that?

Comment: Interesting. My guess is that somehow  `@Transactional` does not apply for `processData()`, so in the second variant every iteration runs within it's own transactional context, thus succeeds.

Comment: @AshishLohia save method can be use both with single object or list of objects as parameter. One can think it will be helpful because it is "bulk insert" but as you see above it is not the case.

Answer (score 26):

As what has been mentioned by [Ori Dar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794744/8706476), there is no really a difference.

However, there is one thing you should notice:the method used to a save a list of elements has been renamed into `<S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)` in [2.2.0.M1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/releases/tag/2.2.0.M1) according to the [repo history](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/commit/b49d7662d94dc9a05b9993f8645c8163f4799373#diff-0781e000cdc895cb9d16c9d5bbd85f32), and the `save` method no longer takes as argument a list.

Since I don't have 50 reputation to comment the answer or question above, I have to write a new answer about this change.

Answer (score 6):

For SpringData Jpa, a cleaner approach will be to use `repository.saveAll` instead of a `for`loop with `repository.save`. `saveAll` will automatically iterate through the list and save it.

`saveAll` is a part of JpaRepository, so no need to define any method.

Comment: This article details a performance difference test : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-save-saveall

Answer (score 2):

saveAll is probably 5-20 times faster because it goes with 1 transaction when .save() opens a new transaction every time it executes.
Making it with one and only transaction makes it faster and not more use memory sparingly

Proof:
[Spring data save vs saveAll performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869277/spring-data-save-vs-saveall-performance)
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-save-saveall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).