# Spring JPA CrudRepository saveAll vs forEach save

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I came across a spring-project with a lot of `<T> CrudRepository` implementations, where lists of objects where saved frequently in two different manners:

```
repository.saveAll(List.of(content));
```

and

```
List.of(content).forEach(Repository::save);
```

I was wondering, is the`saveAll` manner better performance-wise?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869277/spring-data-save-vs-saveall-performance - You should be able to find your answer here.

Comment: @Rozart i see thanks