# Save(List<S>) vs save(Entity) in transaction part two

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Question is a follow on from [CrudRepository and Hibernate: save(List<S>) vs save(Entity) in transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793403/crudrepository-and-hibernate-savelists-vs-saveentity-in-transaction).

If I do not mark the following below with @Transactional. If the database connection drops or something happens as Spring Data JPA is saving a list.  Will the list be rolled back or it will just be partly saved?

```
@Transactional
public void processData() {
   List<MyEntity> entities = ....;
   MyEntityRepository.save(entities);
}
```

Comment: is this method part of a transaction? if yes, then it will be rolled-back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods provided by `CrudRepository` are already transactional.

This is not needed at all, just take a look at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) implementation. All the methods `delete`, deleteAll`,`saveAll`are annotated with`@Transactional`. This means, that default implementation already takes it into account.

Actually whereever there is no `@Transactional` annotation, the default `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, that is on the class level is used.

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on the `MyEntityRepository` implementation.

E.g. If it is generated by spring as a SimpleJpaRepository then it will be rollbacked. Because as shown in the linked question the `save()` method is also annotated with `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {}
```

But for every other implementation? I would say that behaviour is undefined